# Fullcalendar select specific period of time in an event slot

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is their a way to select a specific time in an event? For example, the time slot is from 8AM - 12Am and someone wants to schedule from 10AM to 11AM.

Can anyone give some advises on how to do this ?

Comment: Does businessHours help? http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/ (or) you mean something different?

Comment: No, not that one. I need to get the middle time on a scheduled slot.

Comment: There may be some confusion as to what you are asking. For me, it comes with the wording 'event slot' and 'time in an event'- Events are the objects already placed on the calendar, so are you saying you have an event from 8AM-12AM and you would like to add a new Event from 10AM-11AM? (giving you 2 events)

Comment: I already solved my problem. Thanks for the responses.